# Use IIS 7 to point requests to another server

Tags: iis-7

I have a web site in a server running IIS7. There have been some programming issues with the site so I want to point the host header back to the old web site without having to wait for domain propogation.

Is there any way to forward on a request to a different server based on the host header?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Application Request Routing to do that - it'll set the box up as a reverse proxy for all URLs, by default - by editing the URL Rewrite rules, you can be more specific with that.